# Is this incorrect code generation with arrays of __m256 values a clang bug?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-optimization, avx2

I'm encountering what appears to be a bug causing incorrect code generation with clang 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 trunk. The source that actually triggered the problem is quite complicated, but I've been able to reduce it to this self-contained example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <string.h>

struct simd_pack
{
    enum { num_vectors = 1 };
    __m256i _val[num_vectors];
};

simd_pack load_broken(int8_t *p)
{
    simd_pack pack;
    for (int i = 0; i < simd_pack::num_vectors; ++i) pack._val[i] = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i *>(p + i * 32));
    return pack;
}

void store_broken(int8_t *p, simd_pack pack)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < simd_pack::num_vectors; ++i) _mm256_storeu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i *>(p + i * 32), pack._val[i]);    
}

void test_broken(int8_t *out, int8_t *in1, size_t n)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i + 31 < n; i += 32)
    {
        simd_pack p1 = load_broken(in1 + i);
        store_broken(out + i, p1);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int8_t in_buf[256];
    int8_t out_buf[256];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i) in_buf[i] = i;

    test_broken(out_buf, in_buf, 256);
    if (memcmp(in_buf, out_buf, 256)) std::cout << "test_broken() failed!" << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

A summary of the above: I have a simple type called `simd_pack` that contains one member, an array of one `__m256i` value. In my application, there are operators and functions that take these types, but the problem can be illustrated by the above example. Specifically, `test_broken()` should read from the `in1` array and then just copy its value over to the `out` array. Therefore, the call to `memcmp()` in `main()` should return zero. I compile the above using the following:

```
clang++-3.6 bug_test.cc -o bug_test -mavx -O3
```

I find that on optimization levels `-O0` and `-O1`, the test passes, while on levels `-O2` and `-O3`, the test fails. I've tried compiling the same file with gcc 4.4, 4.6, 4.7, and 4.8, as well as Intel C++ 13.0, and the test passes on all optimization levels.

Taking a closer look at the generated code, here's the assembly generated on optimization level `-O3`:

```
0000000000400a40 <test_broken(signed char*, signed char*, unsigned long)>:
  400a40:       55                      push   %rbp
  400a41:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400a44:       48 81 e4 e0 ff ff ff    and    $0xffffffffffffffe0,%rsp
  400a4b:       48 83 ec 40             sub    $0x40,%rsp
  400a4f:       48 83 fa 20             cmp    $0x20,%rdx
  400a53:       72 2f                   jb     400a84 <test_broken(signed char*, signed char*, unsigned long)+0x44>
  400a55:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400a57:       66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400a5e:       00 00 
  400a60:       c5 fc 10 04 06          vmovups (%rsi,%rax,1),%ymm0
  400a65:       c5 f8 29 04 24          vmovaps %xmm0,(%rsp)
  400a6a:       c5 fc 28 04 24          vmovaps (%rsp),%ymm0
  400a6f:       c5 fc 11 04 07          vmovups %ymm0,(%rdi,%rax,1)
  400a74:       48 8d 48 20             lea    0x20(%rax),%rcx
  400a78:       48 83 c0 3f             add    $0x3f,%rax
  400a7c:       48 39 d0                cmp    %rdx,%rax
  400a7f:       48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  400a82:       72 dc                   jb     400a60 <test_broken(signed char*, signed char*, unsigned long)+0x20>
  400a84:       48 89 ec                mov    %rbp,%rsp
  400a87:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400a88:       c5 f8 77                vzeroupper 
  400a8b:       c3                      retq   
  400a8c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

I'll reproduce the key part for emphasis:

```
  400a60:       c5 fc 10 04 06          vmovups (%rsi,%rax,1),%ymm0
  400a65:       c5 f8 29 04 24          vmovaps %xmm0,(%rsp)
  400a6a:       c5 fc 28 04 24          vmovaps (%rsp),%ymm0
  400a6f:       c5 fc 11 04 07          vmovups %ymm0,(%rdi,%rax,1)
```

This is kind of head-scratching. It first loads 256 bits into `ymm0` using the unaligned move that I asked for, then it stores `xmm0` (which only contains the lower 128 bits of the data that was read) to the stack, then immediately reads 256 bits into `ymm0` from the stack location that was just written to. The effect is that `ymm0`'s upper 128 bits (which get written to the output buffer) are garbage, causing the test to fail.

Is there some good reason why this could be happening, other than just a compiler bug? Am I violating some rule by having the `simd_pack` type hold an array of `__m256i` values? It certainly seems to be related to that; if I change `_val` to be a single value instead of an array, then the generated code works as intended. However, my application requires `_val` to be an array (its length is dependent upon a C++ template parameter).

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like massive fail on the compiler part. There's no reason it should be using `xmm` registers at all when the code is entirely 256-bit. (callee-save registers aside)

Comment: Unless it's strict-aliasing that's getting in the way. But every modern compiler treats SIMD registers as aggregates, so this shouldn't apply.

Comment: Thanks for the input. For what it's worth, I've tried invoking clang with `-fno-strict-aliasing`, but it doesn't affect the generated code.

Comment: FWIW with `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)` this passes with `-O1`, but fails with `-O0`, `-O2` and `-O3`, which is something I've never seen before.

Comment: @PaulR: Yeah, it's definitely strange. Having gotten responses from some of the most experienced SSE/AVX gurus on SO, I'm leaning toward it being a bug. Now I just have to figure out how to report it (the instructions provided by LLVM on collecting a test case seem pretty arcane to me).

Comment: It might be worth filing a bug report with [Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com) too - I'll do this if you're happy for me to pass your test case code on to them ?

Comment: That would be great. If their tracker is public and you could add a link to the report here that would be most broadly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - this is now filed with Apple as RADAR #19803695 - you need a developer account (or at least an Apple ID - free to set up either way) to access http://bugreport.apple.com - I'm not sure if you can see the status of other people's bug reports though.

Comment: Thanks Paul. For what it's worth to others who may see this, you need to be a registered Apple developer to access bugreport.apple.com (which I'm not). I did open a similar report with LLVM directly, so we will see what happens.

Comment: @JasonR: update on this - the bug finally seems to be fixed in the latest Xcode 7 beta released by Apple during WWDC this week. The test case now passes with `Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.53)` on all optimisation levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in clang. The fact that it happened at -O0 is a good clue that the bug is in the front-end, and in this case, it's a dark corner of the x86-64 ABI implementation related to handling of a struct that contains a vector array of exactly size 1!

The bug has been present for years, but this is the first time that anyone has hit it, noticed it, and reported it. Thanks!

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22563

Comment: Indeed this is a dark corner of the ABI. I'm very impressed at the speed at which the bug was diagnosed and a fix proposed. They currently have a patch in code review, hopefully to be available before the upcoming clang 3.6 release.

Comment: The fix for the bug has been merged now, so it looks like it will make it into clang 3.6.