# std::array of AVX intrinsics

Tags: c++, clang, intrinsics, avx

I don't know if there's something missing on my understanding of how AVX intrinsics works with `std::array`, but I'm having a strange issue with Clang when I combine the two.

Sample code:

```
std::array<__m256, 1> gen_data()
{
    std::array<__m256, 1> res;
    res[0] = _mm256_set1_ps(1);
    return res;
}

void main()
{
    auto v = gen_data();
    float a[8];
    _mm256_storeu_ps(a, v[0]);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output from Clang 3.5.0 (upper 4 floats are garbage data):

```
1
1
1
1
8.82272e-39
0
5.88148e-39
0
```

Output from GCC 4.8.2/4.9.1 (expected):

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

If I instead pass `v` into `gen_data` as an output parameter it works just fine on both compilers. I'm willing to accept that this might be a bug in Clang, however I don't know if this might be undefined behavior(*UB*). Testing with Clang 3.7* (svn build) and Clang appears to now give my expected result. If I switch to SSE 128-bit intrinsics (`__m128`) then all compilers give the same expected results.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any UB here? Or is this just a bug in Clang 3.5.0?
2. Is my understanding that __m256 is simply a 32-byte aligned chunk of memory correct? Or is there something else special about it that I have to be careful with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like this is clang bug that is now fixed, we can see this from this [bug report](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22563) , which demonstrates a very similar problem using regular arrays.

Assuming `std::array` implements its storage similar to this:

```
T elems[N];
```

which both `libc++` and `libstdc++` seem to do then this should analogous. One of the comments says:

> However, libc++'s `std::array<__m256i, 1>` does not work at any optimization level.

The bug report was actually based off of this SO question: [Is this incorrect code generation with arrays of __m256 values a clang bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28462707/1708801) which is very similar but deals with the regular array case.

The bug report contains one possible work-around, which the OP stated is sufficient:

> In my actual code, `num_vectors` is calculated based on some C++ template parameters to the `simd_pack` type. In many cases, that comes out to be 1, but it also is often greater than 1. Your observation gives me an idea, though; I could try to introduce a template specialization that catches the case where `num_vectors == 1`. It could instead just use a single `__m256` member instead of an array of size 1. I'll have to check to see how feasible that is.

Comment: You are correct. Specifically, this was a problem with arrays of length one where the element type was an AVX vector type. It was quickly fixed after it was reported, and I believe the fix was incorporated into the clang 3.6 release. You might try that version if you don't want to use the trunk.

Comment: Also for context, [here is the SO question that was originally posted about the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462707/is-this-incorrect-code-generation-with-arrays-of-m256-values-a-clang-bug).

Comment: @JasonR oh, you know that is actually in the bug report and I missed it, let me update my answer. Well done question as well +1.

Comment: As a suitable workaround (suggested in the bug report), I created a minimalistic std::array replacement which has a specialization for unity sized arrays to contain a single element rather than an array of size 1.

Comment: @helloworld922 I missed that suggestion, I should have seen that, I will add it in.